# How to push_back an integer to a string?

Tags: c++, string, char, int, push-back

Right now, I'm preparing to do a homework assignment by first sorting out what I'm going to do in my methods. For one of them, I have to prepare a list of names to be added to a list in the form A1, B2, C3 ... etc. What I am testing right now is a way to add them via a for loop. Please note that I am not doing the whole thing yet, I'm just ensuring that the items are made in the correct form. I have the following code:

```
list<string> L; //the list to hold the data in the form A1, B2, etc.
char C = 'A'; //the char value to hold the alphabetical letters
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{ 
    string peas; //a string to hold the values, they will be pushed backed here
    peas.push_back(C++); //adds an alphabetical letter to the temp string, incrementing on every loop
    peas.push_back(i); //is supposed to add the number that i represents to the temp string
    L.push_back(peas); //the temp string is added to the list
}
```

The letter chars add and increment to the value just fine (they show up as A B C etc.), but the problem I am having is that when I push_back the integer value, it doesn't actually push_back an integer value, but an ascii value related to the integer (that's my guess -- it returns emoticons).

I'm thinking the solution here is to turn the integer value into a char, but, so far, looking that up has been very confusing. I have tried to_string (gives me errors) and char(i) (same result as just i) but none have worked. So basically: **how can I add i as a char value representing the actual integer number it holds and not as an ascii value?**

My TA usually doesn't actually read the code sent to him and the instructor takes far too long to respond, so I was hoping I could get this issue resolved here.

Thank you!

Comment: If `i` is never greater than 9, you can use `('0' + i)`

Comment: `to_string` should work, question is why it does not work in your case. What error do you get and what exactly have you tried for that case?

Comment: You *have* to use `push_back` for this?

Comment: @DanielFrey I get "more than instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Comment: `peas.push_back(C++); peas.append(std::to_string(i))` would do what you want, it seems, and handle insertions passed `J`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`push_back` appends *individual characters* to the string. What you want is to *convert* a number *to* a string and then concatenate this string to another string. That’s a fundamentally different operation.

To convert a number to a string, use [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). To concatenate strings, you can simply use `+`:

```
std::string prefix = std::string(1, C++);
L.push_back(prefix + std::to_string(i));
```

If your compiler doesn’t support C++11 yet, there’s the solution using a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << C++ << i;
L.push_back(ostr.str());
```

Comment: No need for `peas` in that case, just push back `ostr.str()` to `L` directly.